# Error: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'IMAGE()'. Expected 2, received 3

Tags: formula, formula-field, images, image-formula

```
IF(
    LastActivityDate < DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY()), DAY(TODAY())) - 30,
    IMAGE("/img/samples/flag_green.gif", "green"),
    IF(
        LastActivityDate > DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY()), DAY(TODAY())) - 30,
        IF(
            LastActivityDate < DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY()), DAY(TODAY())) - 60,
            IMAGE("/img/samples/flag_yellow.gif", "yellow"),
            IF(
                LastActivityDate > DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY()), DAY(TODAY())) - 60,
                IMAGE("/img/samples/flag_red.gif", "red")
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: When I paste this in, I get an IF is missing a third argument

Comment: This error is impossible to encounter given the formula you've provided us

Comment: the solution to these issues is selective reduction .. start with the simplest formula and add pieces in until you get the error

Answer (score 1):

Your innermost IF statement needs a 3rd parameter

```
IF(
    LastActivityDate < DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY()), DAY(TODAY())) - 30,
    IMAGE("/img/samples/flag_green.gif", "green"),
    IF(
        LastActivityDate > DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY()), DAY(TODAY())) - 30,
        IF(
            LastActivityDate < DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY()), DAY(TODAY())) - 60,
            IMAGE("/img/samples/flag_yellow.gif", "yellow"),
            IF(
                LastActivityDate > DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY()), DAY(TODAY())) - 60,
                IMAGE("/img/samples/flag_red.gif", "red"),
                [something else is required here]
            )
        )
    )
)
```